# How to be specific about my car?

Tags: compound

My question is simple, if someone asks me: *Hast du ein Auto?*. Can I say something  like: *Ja, Ich habe ein Volkswagenauto*, or *Fiatauto?* Or should I separate the words?

Comment: *Hast du ein Auto? — Ja, einen VW.* (not Volkswagen, but "Fauweh"). But it's more common to say the type of car instead of the brand for VW cars because of its high market share in Germany. *Hast du ein Auto? — Ja, einen Bora.*

Comment: Dass jemand so ein spießiges Auto wie einen Bora hat, würde er niemals als erstes erwähnen. Bora-Fahrer sagen, sie hätten einen VW ;)

Comment: Volkswagen ist vollkommen in Ordnung und wird auch benutzt, nur Volkswagenauto sagt niemand oder auch Fiatauto nicht. Was sollte aber die Trennung der Wörter bewirken?

Comment: Haha, ein japanischer Kollege war ganz stolz auf seinen Bora VR6. Obwohl es den nicht als Rechtslenker gab und er in Japan deshalb total unpraktisch ist. Es ist das Brüllen aus dem Korsett der Spießerkarre, das den Bora verkäuflich gemacht hat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the "auto." Just say, "Ich habe einen Volkswagen," or "Ich habe einen Fiat." The "Auto" is understood once you name the type.

Comment: It is worth noting that it *has* to be "ein*en* Fiat". Cars referenced by their brand are masculine, even though "Auto" is neuter; and yes, this makes little sense.

Comment: Interesting side fact: Motorbikes referred to by brand are *feminine* for some obscure reason, even though the Motorbike is neuter as well - "Ich fahre eine Yamaha". - "Ich fahre einen BMW" vs. "Ich fahre eine BMW": The former clearly means a car, the latter a bike.

Comment: @KilianForth: It makes sense as it may be based on *der Wagen*. The word even appears at the end of *Volkswagen*. Also note that some vehicle brands are rather feminine, such as *die Vespa* or *die Isetta*. I am not sure whether the difference is indeed cars vs. motorbikes, as tofro claims. It is possible, though, and fits with the fact that motorbikers speak of their vehicles as *die Maschine*. The same applies to airplanes (*die Boeing*, *die MiG*, *die Tomcat*), again unless the brand name is very close to a differently gendered German word (*der Airbus*).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper *Isetta* is not a brand, but a make. "**Die** Isetta ist **ein** BMW". Same applies to "**die** Ente ist **ein** Citroen".

Comment: @tofro: Hmm, aren't some makes usually registered as brands? Or is that exclusively called trademark then, not brand? In any case, Tomcat would then be a make, as well. I 5hink the gender logic applies to brands and makes alike.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Same logic for brands and types applies: No, it doesn't - See "Ente" vs. "Citroen" and "Isetta" vs. "BMW" or "Isabella" vs. "Borgward" and many more.

Comment: @tofro: I don't understand. It looks like the same logic - a basic gender based on the vehicle type, overridden in some cases if the particular name strongly suggests a different gender.

Comment: I can't think of any car named by brand that would be other than masculine - This seems to be a strict rule.  For types, though, there doesn't seem to be such a strict rule.